# 'absolute' Positioned View Position is Changing After the Initial Render

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using NextJs and one of my view has `absolute` positioning.

That view's position is changing after initial render according to this block:

```
.medal {
  height: 15vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -20px;
}
```

Why my view's position is changing 20 px to top, -20px to left after the initial render?

What I expect is that my view should be rendered initially 20px to top, -20px to left.

Edit:

```
<main style={{ padding: 20, }}> //If I remove the padding, issue disappears 
  <Grow
    in={secondScreenActive}
    style={{ transformOrigin: '0 0 0' }}
    {...(secondScreenActive ? { timeout: 1000 } : {})}
  >
    <div className={styles.cardPerson}>

      <div style={{ flex: 1, display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', width: '100%', justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <div style={{width:'1vw'}}>
          <Medal style={{height:'15vw',position: 'absolute', top:  20, left: -30}}/>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </Grow>
</main>
```

CSS

```
.cardPerson {
  height: 30vh;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgb(86, 136, 143), Black);
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

**SOLVED**

I moved `<main style={{ padding: 20, }}>` to after `<Grow>`, issue solved.

```
  <Grow
    in={secondScreenActive}
    style={{ transformOrigin: '0 0 0' }}
    {...(secondScreenActive ? { timeout: 1000 } : {})}
  >
   <main style={{ padding: 20, }}> 
    <div className={styles.cardPerson}>

      <div style={{ flex: 1, display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', width: '100%', justifyContent: 'space-between', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <div style={{width:'1vw'}}>
          <Medal style={{height:'15vw',position: 'absolute', top:  20, left: -30}}/>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
   </main>
  </Grow>
```

Comment: Have you added transition property on the element? Also, can you verify if this also occurs on production mode? Another thing, where have you put this code? Are you applying it inside a `useEffect` hook?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `material-ui` `grow` animation. After removing the animation from the code, issue disappeared. `useEffect` has no relation to animation. Is there any way to resolve the issue? **Issue also occurs on the production mode.**